# Laravel: OrderBy the paginated Eloquent relationship result

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

My application uses Laravel 5.2

I have two models: Links and Affiliates. The relationship between them is: Link hasMany Affiliates.
When I want the Affiliates for a Link, I'd like to paginate the result, which works as expected, but I also want to Order by the result. How do I do that?

This is how my current code is:

```
$affiliates = $link->affiliates->paginate(50, ['*'], 'p')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('visitor_ip', 'desc');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$affiliates = Affiliate::where('link_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('visitor_ip', 'desc')->paginate(50, ['*'], 'p');
```

Comment: Result: BadMethodCallException, Method orderBy does not exist.

Comment: How do you use `$link =` before the posted line?

Comment: This is what I do with the Link: $link = Link::find($id);
$subscribers = $link->subscribers()->paginate(env('SUBSCRIBERS_LIST', 50));

Comment: So, you using paginate twice, I think that's the problem.

Comment: But I use Paginate on two different models/result sets

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try to replace `$link->` with `Link::where( // search by id )->`. Maybe the problem is with conflicting `find()` and `paginate()` here, cause both act like `get()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105128/discussion-between-zoli-and-alexey-mezenin).